# Is Frank in 'Frank' autistic?

Tags: character, frank

I just saw [the movie *Frank*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1605717/) and really liked it.  The mask (which I understand could be a hyperbole of this situation) being the least of a reason why I am asking this, the most being his communication and incoherent mumbling style as well as avoiding eye contact once the mask was off, is Frank supposed to be a very awkward and introverted autistic man?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autistic, no. Deeply introverted and borderline mentally ill, absolutely.

[This interview](http://www.theguardian.com/culture/2014/jan/12/frank-sidebottom-movie-michael-fassbender-chris-sievey) in the Guardian with the real Jon Ronson (who wrote the film) gives us a pretty solid evaluation of "Frank's" mental state:

> "The moment the head is placed the change occurs. Not merely a change
>   in attitude or outlook but a journey from one person to the other. I
>   completely believe that Chris was born as two people." **Middles likens
>   Chris to transgender people, trapped in the wrong body.**

and there's some extra info in [this BBC interview](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-26820227) that suggests that the "head thing" was more than just an act

> So to what extent was Frank Sidebottom just an act, a part Chris was
>   playing? Or did it become an alter ego, a completely different
>   persona? "**You've got to be careful not to psychoanalyse him too much
>   because it might be wrong,"** Jon Ronson cautions.
>
> **"But my feeling is that if Chris was incredibly chaotic and Frank was
>   incredibly innocent, there's got to be a reason for that, right? "And
>   to encase yourself in this fake head… there has to be a reason. It was
>   safer. Frank was a calmer, safer place to be than Chris."**